# Sum of two arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

Im pretty new at Java Programming. I have an assignment here that tells me to find the sum of two arrays. Simple enough really, but I have a hard time figuring out all the syntaxes. Here is the question that I am talking about [Here is the question that I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNb0K.jpg) and below is how far I have managed to go.

### Main Class

```
package arraysum;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArraySum extends ArrayTwo{


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int result[] = new int[10];


    }
}
```

### Sub Class One

```
 package arraysum;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayOne{
    int arr1[] = new int[10];
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public ArrayOne(){
      System.out.println("Enter the elements of the 1st array");
        for(int x=0;x<10;x++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter an element");
            arr1[x]=input.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

### Sub Class Two

```
    package arraysum;

public class ArrayTwo extends ArrayOne{
    int arr2[] = new int[10];

    public ArrayTwo(){
    System.out.println("Enter the elements of the 2nd array");
        for(int y=0;y<10;y++){
            System.out.println("Enter an element");
            arr2[y]=input.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help at all would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "sum"?

Comment: he has to add up the elements with index 0, those with index 2, ... se he'll get a new array with the results.
Kudabe: why do you create a class for each array? that makes no real sense.

Comment: someone can earn easy +15 here

Comment: You are summing up the values located in the same spot in two arrays. As long as their sizes match, you should just do a for-loop starting at 0 while the variable is less than the size of one of the arrays. Use that loop variable to pull each value out of the 2 arrays and then add them together.

Comment: I don't get what has to happen here: The program should be able to conduct the addition() and substraction() methods invoked by respective object(s).

Comment: The thing is, according to the rubrics, the program must consist of constructors, obejcts, member methods, a seperate main class and OO concepts like inheritence, polymorphism and abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

Your sum and subtract method should look like this

```
public class ArrayMath {
    public static int[] sum(int [] arrOne,int [] arrTwo) {
        if(arrOne.length!=arrTwo.length) {// check if length is same
            return null;
        }
        int[] returnArray = new int[arrOne.length];
        for(int i=0;i<arrOne.length;i++) { // adding with same index
            returnArray[i]=arrOne[i]+arrTwo[i];
        }
        return returnArray;
    }

    public static int[] subtract(int [] arrOne,int [] arrTwo) {
        if(arrOne.length!=arrTwo.length) { // checking length is same
            return null;
        }
        int[] returnArray = new int[arrOne.length];
        for(int i=0;i<arrOne.length;i++) { // subtracting with same index
            returnArray[i]=arrOne[i]-arrTwo[i];
        }
        return returnArray;
    }
}
```

Your main should look like :

```
public class ArraySum {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the size of the arrays : ");
      int size = input.nextInt();
      int arrayOne[] = new int[size];
      int arrayTwo[] = new int[size];
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
         System.out.println("Enter the "+i+"th elements of the 1st array");
         arrayOne[i]=input.nextInt();
         System.out.println("Enter the "+i+"th elements of the 2st array");
         arrayTwo[i]=input.nextInt();
      }

      // Now you can call the methods
      int[] additionArray=ArrayMath.sum(arrayOne,arrayTwo);
      int[] subtractionArray=ArrayMath.subtract(arrayOne, arrayTwo);

      if(additionArray==null){
         System.out.println("Both array are not of same size hence cannot add");
      } else {
         System.out.println("Addition of array is");
         Arrays.sort(additionArray);
         for(int i=0; i<additionArray.length;i++){
            System.out.println(additionArray[i]+" ");
         }
      }
      if(subtractionArray==null){
         System.out.println("Both array are not of same size hence cannot subtract");
      } else {
         System.out.println("Subtraction of array is");
         Arrays.sort(subtractionArray);
         for(int i=0; i<subtractionArray.length;i++){
            System.out.println(subtractionArray[i]+" ");
         }
      }

   }
}
```

---

Another way of doing it would be.
ArrayMath class

```
public class ArrayMath {
    private int[] array;

    public ArrayMath(int[] arr){
        this.array=arr;
    }

    public int[] sum(int [] arr) {
        if(array.length!=arr.length){
            return null;
        }
        int[] returnArray = new int[array.length];
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
            returnArray[i]=array[i]+arr[i];
        }
        return returnArray;
    }

    public int[] subtract(int [] arr) {
        if(array.length!=arr.length){
            return null;
        }
        int[] returnArray = new int[array.length];
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
            returnArray[i]=array[i]-arr[i];
        }
        return returnArray;
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class ArraySum {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the size of the arrays : ");
      int size = input.nextInt();
      int arrayOne[] = new int[size];
      int arrayTwo[] = new int[size];
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
         System.out.println("Enter the "+i+"th elements of the 1st array");
         arrayOne[i]=input.nextInt();
         System.out.println("Enter the "+i+"th elements of the 2st array");
         arrayTwo[i]=input.nextInt();
      }

      ArrayMath arrayMath = new ArrayMath(arrayOne);
      // Now you can call the methods
      int[] additionArray=arrayMath.sum(arrayTwo);
      int[] subtractionArray=arrayMath.subtract(arrayTwo);

      if(additionArray==null){
         System.out.println("Both array are not of same size hence cannot add");
      } else {
         System.out.println("Addition of array is");
         Arrays.sort(additionArray);
         for(int i=0; i<additionArray.length;i++){
            System.out.println(additionArray[i]+" ");
         }
      }
      if(subtractionArray==null){
         System.out.println("Both array are not of same size hence cannot subtract");
      } else {
         System.out.println("Subtraction of array is");
         Arrays.sort(subtractionArray);
         for(int i=0; i<subtractionArray.length;i++){
            System.out.println(subtractionArray[i]+" ");
         }
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: You missed the sorting part. You should add something like `Arrays.sort(array)` for sorting in ascending order.

Comment: Don't the subtraction and addition methods mean that you also should be able to do that math on any element of the two arrays? Something like `int sum = add(arr1[2] + arr2[5]);` or `int sum = subtract(arr1[9] - arr[3]);` for example and print the outcome?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't enough reputation to comment, so I'll answer.

you don't need to create a class for each array. just do as follow (just a pseudocode)

```
initialize array1;
foreach elem in array:
    sumArray[pos] = read user input;

initialize array2;
foreach elem in array:
    sumArray[pos] = read user input;

initialize sumArray
foreach elem in array:
    sumArray[pos] = array1[pos] + array2[pos];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it will be give u the addition

```
package com.arraysum;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Addition {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter the two array size..");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = input.nextInt();
        int[] one= new int[size],two = new int[size];
        System.out.println("Enter the array elements of Array-One");
        for (int i = 0; i <size; i++) {
            one[i]=input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the array elements of Array-Two");
        for (int i = 0; i <size; i++) {
            two[i]=input.nextInt();
        }
        Addition(one,two);

    }

    private static void Addition(int[] one, int[] two){
        System.out.print("Array One"+"\t");
        for (int i = 0; i <one.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(one[i] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Array Two"+"\t");
        for (int i = 0; i <two.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(two[i]+ "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("---------------------");
        int result[]=new int[one.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            result[i]=one[i]+two[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Sum Of Two Arrays ");
        System.out.print(" Sum "+"\t"+"\t");
        Arrays.sort(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(result[i]+"\t");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you need, you should skip deal with class hierachy.
Simply initialize the two array, and create a new sumArray and copy the values in it.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArTestSum {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        int[] ar1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        int[] ar2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        int[] arSum = new int[ar1.length + ar2.length]; // it is OK because
                                                        // known in compile time

        int i = 0;
        for (int val : ar1) {
            arSum[i++] = val;
        }
        for (int val : ar2) {
            arSum[i++] = val;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arSum));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is code snippet for your problem. Hope this will be useful to you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int arr1[] = new int[10];
    int result[] = new int[10];

    System.out.println("Enter the elements of the 1st array");
    for (int x = 0; x < arr1.length; x++) {
        arr1[x] = input.nextInt();
    }

    int arr2[] = new int[10];
    System.out.println("Enter the elements of the 2nd array");
    for (int x = 0; x < arr2.length; x++) {
        arr2[x] = input.nextInt();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        result[i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i];
    }
    Arrays.sort(result);
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(result[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SumOfArrayPlusArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3};
        int[] arr2 = {4, 5, 6};

        System.out.println(arrayPlusArray(arr1, arr2));
    }

    public static int arrayPlusArray(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
        int sumOfArrays = 0;
        for(int i: arr1) {
            sumOfArrays += i;
        }
        for (int i: arr2) {
            sumOfArrays += i;
        }
        return sumOfArrays;
    }

}
```